# how to pass params in url in reactjs using react router version4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, routeparams

in react-router version 4, how to pass params in url, in older version i was using this.props.params. but it is depricated in this version so please help me.
i am sending params this way

```
<Link to={"/dashboard/viewProfile/"+id+"/"+type}>View Profile</Link>
```

and in routing

```
<Route path="/dashboard/viewProfile/:id/:type" render={() => <ViewProfile />} />
```

so now in view profile component how to get these params.

Comment: issue is in the route, use this: `<Route path="/dashboard/viewProfile/:id/:type" render={(props) => <ViewProfile {...props} /> } />`, you need to pass the props into `ViewProfile` or use `component` instead of `render` with route.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your router element :

```
 <Router>
      <div>
        <Route path="/topics/:name" component={Topic} />
      </div>
    </Router>
```

With param in path and you can get the param from the Topic Componenent for example :

```
export default function Topic(props) {
  return <h1>{props.match.params.name}</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `props.match.params.id` and `props.match.params.type` to access the params.

Refer this example - https://jaketrent.com/post/access-route-params-react-router-v4/